# Rename [googleplacesautocomplete] to [google-places-autocomplete]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Almost all Google Maps and other related Google libraries tags are now following the same *naming convention*, for example [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api), [google-directions-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-directions-api), [google-geocoding-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-geocoding-api) etc.

I would therefore suggest to rename the [googleplacesautocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/googleplacesautocomplete) tag to [google-places-autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-autocomplete).

Comment: I can't search for deleted questions, but considering its length of 24, the tag was possibly created before [the additional length from 25 to 35 in Aug 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/241919).

Comment: The [oldest post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46573335/revisions) that I can find (using SEDE) that had the tag at creation was created October 2017 and that was deleted. Looks like the current iteration of the tag was created in 2019, which was after the increase.